# Can a YTPMV reupload be taken down by the original YTPMV uploader who has voluntarily removed it from the platform?

Tags: copyright, youtube, parody

Without going too deeply into the specifics...

One of my favorite YTPMV’s was taken down (by its own creator for some reason) from the YT platform. It was a YTPMV of one of Eminem’s songs. The YTPMV creator definitely did not get permission from Eminem or his team.

After reuploading the video to YT using the Wayback Machine, the YTPMV creator, not Eminem or his team, is telling me to take down the reupload because it is “their” work, and they want it removed entirely from YT. The video is entirely made of copyrighted content butchered and edited together into a musical parody.

The video uses old Nintendo CD-i animation, with instrumentation and parodical lyrics from one of Eminem’s songs, and a watermark of the uploader’s previous username in the top right.

Can this user force me to take down the video? All visual and audio content in the video is 100% owned by other individuals and companies that certainly did not give him/her permission; only the arrangement of the clips and snippets is original.

I would fully understand if Nintendo or Eminem would make me take down the reupload. But does the original YTPMV uploader (who is now erasing it) have any basis for ownership of the video, or sufficient grounds to remove my reupload?

Comment: What does "YTPMV" stand for?

Comment: I don't think the definition of the term really matters - it's some kind of work protected by copyright.

Comment: @nick012000 YouTube Poop Music Video

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding how copyright can be split among multiple people.

In this case, the work is definitely protected by copyright, by everyone who made a substantial contribution. The work can be distributed if and only if they *all* agree, i.e. both the creator from the question and Eminem. If there's no such agreement, the work cannot be distributed. Essentially, they all have a veto.

Here, the creator is legally in the right to veto this particular distribution. Even Enimem can't distribute it. OP certainly can't.

Comment: The editor of the YTPMV might actually have *all* the rights if it is criticism or commentary against Eminem/the stock photos, then even Eminem et al. couldn't block it!